# C++: invalid conversion from ‘BaseNode*’ to ‘Match*’

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast

All objects in my program inherit from a Container class. The Container class has a `virtual BaseNode* getParent() const;` method and a `virtual void setParent(BaseNode *p);` method.

I have a `Set` class (Set in a tennis match, not a data structure) which has the `Match` class as it's parent (via `setParent()`) but since `Set` inherits from `Container`,  The program creates a tree structure from the top down and the `Set` class is a child, it doesn't need to have methods to track and maintain information about it's parent beyond what `Container` provides.

The error `C++: invalid conversion from  ‘BaseNode*’ to ‘Match*’` shows up in the method below when I try to compile my program. (`Player* getPlayer1() const;` only exists in the `Match` class)

```
Player* Set::getPlayer1() const{
    return getParent()->getPlayer1();
}
```

This is my inheritance structure for Match. (Note that `TreeNode` is a template)

```
Match -> TreeNode<Set> -> BaseNode -> Container
```

I don't understand why I'm getting a conversation error. I have tried reading my textbook but it's a rather poor reference. Google just provided too much irrelevant information.

**Edit**

```
Player* Set::getPlayer1() const{
    return dynamic_cast<Match>(getParent())->getPlayer1();
}
```

causes

```
error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘#‘obj_type_ref’ not supported by dump_expr#<expression error>((&((const Set*)this)->Set::<anonymous>))’ (of type ‘class BaseNode*’) to type ‘class Match’ (target is not pointer or reference)
```

**Edit 2**

I just realized I need `dynamic_cast<Match*>` which works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `getParent()` returns a `BaseNode*`, which could be a pointer to any type of `BaseNode` - it might point to an unrelated class that also derives from `BaseNode`.  If you're 100% sure that the parent must be of type `Match`, you should cast the parent to a `Match*` first, and then you can call `getPlayer()` on that:

```
Player* Set::getPlayer1() const{
    return dynamic_cast<Match*>(getParent())->getPlayer1();
}
```

If the parent isn't necessary a `Match`, then `dynamic_cast` might return NULL, so be sure to check for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you really need to re-organize your hierarchy and method names...  This has nothing to do with your question, but in general it seems hard to fathom why Set inherits from Match.  (doesn't a match have sets?)

games are composed of points, sets are composed of games and a match is composed of sets...  a point is won by a player.

you should probably structure it more closely to the real world.

just my $.02

EDIT

I'd probably have a Match object that contains a map of sets (map   i.e. set one, two three, etc) and the Method Player(int) rather than Player1() and player2().  Also it does not seem necessary to have a method for player in the Set class.  A Set would point to a match in which it is being played.

Comment: Set inherits from Container, Match inherits from TreeNode. The entire structure is tree shaped. Matches have Set children. The details of a game aren't required for this application so Set contains the statistics.

Comment: Scary but I have about 80% less code and I've learn a heck of alot more than I would have doing it without inheritance.

Comment: right, but the inheritance is all wrong.  It does not map the real world.  I don't mean to be negative, just trying to help out.

Comment: What you just edited your comment to is the structure I have. A TreeNode has a vector of Container objects--"Children"--within it. So a Match would have a vector of Matches. The getPlayer1() method on the Set class just gets Player1 from it's "parent" which is a Match class.

Comment: I didn't say Set inherited from Match. I said Match was the parent of Set. Parent is an instance variable for all Containers. I may have not been very clear but I never said Set inherits from Match.

Comment: My misunderstanding then.  In my world, parent/child means inherit when talking of C++.

Comment: :) I can see how that can be confusing but I have done alot of work with tree structures in code lately so I've been using them in that sense.